# Modifying WooCommerce Login to Utilize "client_code" and "password" Fields Instead of Default "email" and "password"

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, custom-authentication

I'm working on a WordPress project with WooCommerce integration. The current WooCommerce login form requires users to enter their email and password for authentication. However, I need to customize this process to allow users to use their "code_client" as the username and the associated "password" field for authentication instead of the default "email" and "password." Despite implementing a custom authentication logic and form, I'm encountering an issue where submitting the form redirects me to the default WordPress login page with an error message indicating empty username and password fields.

To achieve this customization, I started by implementing a custom authentication logic using PHP. The primary objective was to leverage the "codeClient" field as the unique identifier and utilize the corresponding "password" field for authentication. I incorporated the following code snippet into my WordPress setup:

```
// Custom Authentication Logic
function custom_authenticate($user, $code_client, $password) {
    if (!empty($code_client) && !empty($password)) {
        $user_data = get_user_by('code_client', $code_client);

        if ($user_data && wp_check_password($password, $user_data->user_pass, $user_data->ID)) {
            return new WP_User($user_data->ID);
        }
    }

    return $user;
}

add_filter('authenticate', 'custom_authenticate', 10, 3);

// Modify Login Error Messages
function custom_login_errors($error) {
    return 'Incorrect code client or password.';
}

add_filter('login_errors', 'custom_login_errors');
```

With this code, I expected that users could use their "codeClient" and "password" fields in the custom login form, which I created as part of this customization effort. I anticipated that successful authentication would lead users to a designated page within my website.

However, upon submitting the custom login form with the "codeClient" and "password" inputs, the behavior was not as anticipated. Instead of successful authentication and redirection, I encountered an unexpected issue. After submitting the form, I was immediately redirected to the default WordPress login page. Furthermore, the page displayed an error message indicating that both the "username" and "password" fields were empty, even though I had filled them out.

I have taken several steps to troubleshoot the issue, including verifying that the field names in the code ("code_client" and "user_pass") match those in the database, enabling debug mode to catch potential errors, and reviewing server error logs for any relevant information. Despite these efforts, I have been unable to resolve the redirection issue and successfully authenticate users using the custom "codeClient" and "password" fields.

My goal is to overcome this redirection problem and successfully implement the custom login functionality using the "codeClient" and "password" fields for authentication. I greatly appreciate any insights or solutions that can help me address this issue and achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: This needs clarity. What does your custom login form look like, what parameters does it actually send?